# How to temporarily ignore punctuation? python

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i'm trying to write a function to decode a message the user entered

```
decypherbook = {'0000':8, '0001':1, '0010':0, '0011':9, '0100':5, '0101':3, '0110':7, '0111':2, '1110':4, '1111':6} 
userdecode = raw_input("Enter the number you want to de-cypher: ")
def decode(cypher, msg):
    length = len(msg)
    decoded = ""
    key_index = 0 ## starting position of a key in message
    while key_index < length: 
        key = msg[key_index:key_index + 4]
        decoded += str(cypher[key])
        key_index += 4
    return decoded

print "After de-cypher: ", decode(decypherbook, userdecode)
```

but if the user input a message like "0001,0001", which i would like the result be "1,1". How could i make my code temporarily ignore punctuation so it doesn't mess up with my indexing +4 in my code and still able to print out the punctuation later?

Comment: Don't know how robust you want this to be, but you should know that in some countries, they use a `.` to seperate thousands, and a `,` for the decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the next characeter is an integer. If not, just add it to the string and continue to the next character:

```
def decode(cypher, msg):
    length = len(msg)
    decoded = ""
    key_index = 0 ## starting position of a key in message
    while key_index < length: 
        key = msg[key_index:key_index + 4]
        decoded += str(cypher[key])
        key_index += 4

        # Pass every non digit after
        while key_index < length and not msg[key_index].isdigit():
             decoded += msg[key_index]
             key_index += 1

    return decoded
```

Here is an example of execution:

```
>>> def decode(cypher, msg):
... # ...
>>> decode(decypherbook, '0001,0010')
'1,0'
```

Side note: You could also prefer to make a list as a buffer instead of recreating a string every time (string are immutable, every `+=` creates a new object) and do `''.join(buffer)` at the end. Just for performance purpose.

Comment: if the user enters "0001,0001", the "," messed index up, so the result would be "1,". is there a way we can ignore "," because the cypher key is every 4 index, but rather than completely remove "," we temporarily ignore it, so the result be "11" then at the end of program put it back and result becomes "1,1"

Comment: This is somehow what I am doing with my corrected algorithm: I am skipping every non digit characters between group of 4 characters. Does it not work?

Comment: i tried it with your code but the results come out as "1," so close, i can't see where is wrong

Comment: @user3620442 I have corrected my code and post an example (works for me)

Comment: woah how did change key_index < length position changed the outcome? anyway thank you so much

Comment: Because at the end, it was checking if the next character was not a number BUT there was no characters left so it failed. Now, if you are already at the end of the string, it won't test the second condition (the `and` is interrupted if the first condition is `False`)

Answer (score 0):

Use split method from string object

```
userdecode = raw_input("Enter the number you want to de-cypher: ")
userdecode_list = userdecode.split(",")
```

And than call your function  like this with join method from string object

```
print "After de-cypher: ", decode(decypherbook, "".join(userdecode_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like `replace` matches your need more.

```
def decode(cypher, msg):
    for key, value in cypher.items():
        msg = msg.replace(key, str(value))

    return msg
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun-one-liner (which assumes `userdecode` is guaranteed to be of the form `r"(\d{4},)*"`)

```
def decode(cypher, msg):
    return ",".join([str(cypher[x]), for x in userdecode.split(",")])
```